# Assign Group ID Based on Time Interval PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark data frame like the following (snap - i can have multiple dates)

```
UID Time
1   10/1/2016 7:25:52 AM
1   10/1/2016 8:53:38 AM
1   10/1/2016 11:18:50 AM
1   10/1/2016 11:19:32 AM
2   10/1/2016 10:25:36 AM
2   10/1/2016 10:28:08 AM
3   10/1/2016 10:57:41 AM
3   10/1/2016 8:57:10 PM
```

I want to assign a unique identifier to each set of actions carried out by a user at most N hours after the previous one. As an example, with a time range of 3 hours, the output should be something like this:

```
UID Time                   GROUP_ID
1   10/1/2016 7:25:52 AM   1
1   10/1/2016 8:53:38 AM   1
1   10/1/2016 11:18:50 AM  1
1   10/1/2016 3:19:32 PM   2
2   10/1/2016 10:25:36 AM  3
2   10/1/2016 10:28:08 AM  3
3   10/1/2016 10:57:41 AM  4
3   10/1/2016 8:57:10 PM   5
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if there is another entry `1 10/1/2016 8:00:00 PM`?

Comment: GROUP_ID column would be 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6

Comment: which time that new row is compared with?

Comment: This one  1   10/1/2016 3:19:32 PM   2
(last done by that user)

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about it is to divide the time difference by the interval you want, which gives you a time bucket.

Then, `dense_rank` to get a consecutive group numbers.

```
# interval in seconds
interval = 3 * 60 * 60
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time')
df = (df.withColumn('time', F.to_timestamp('time', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a'))
      .withColumn('grp', F.floor(
          (F.col('time').cast('long') - F.min('time').over(w).cast('long')) 
           / interval))
      .withColumn('grp', F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('id', 'grp'))))
```

Result

```
+---+-------------------+---+
| id|               time|grp|
+---+-------------------+---+
|  1|2016-10-01 07:25:52|  1|
|  1|2016-10-01 08:53:38|  1|
|  1|2016-10-01 11:18:50|  2|  # this is different from your expected result. but this is more than 3hrs since 7:25
|  1|2016-10-01 11:19:32|  2|
|  1|2016-10-01 20:00:00|  3|
|  2|2016-10-01 10:25:36|  4|
|  2|2016-10-01 10:28:08|  4|
|  3|2016-10-01 10:57:41|  5|
|  3|2016-10-01 20:57:10|  6|
+---+-------------------+---+
```